# Why is there a difference in time when applying Breadth First Search on these two different graphs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

Why is it that applying BFS to an adjacency matrix is Total: **O(V<sup>2</sup> + E) = O(V<sup>2</sup>)**

And for an Adjacency list its Total: **O(V + E) = O(E)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An adjacency matrix is implemented as a V-by-V structure.  In order to determine whether a vertex is adjacent at the current level, you must walk through all possibly-adjacent vertices.  So for every vertex you visit, you must check for `V` adjacent vertices.

With lists, you don't need this, because the list stores only those vertices that are adjacent.  Thus for each vertex visited, you never touch vertices that are not adjacent.